# fill form programmatically in Android Webview - JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

I'm trying to automatically fill a form from the website of my school. 
I've seen some ways to do with javascrip.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.navegador_siiau_layout);

    navegador_siiau = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv_navegador_siiau);
    navegador_siiau.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    navegador_siiau.loadUrl("http://siiauescolar.siiau.udg.mx/wus/gupprincipal.inicio");
    navegador_siiau.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            String user="207512134";
            String pwd="FENMAA";
            view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('p_codigo_c').value = '"+user+"';document.getElementsByName('p_clave_c').value='"+pwd+"';");
        }
    });



}
```

The result is a blank page with the last string I try to put in the form... 
What can I do to fill and submit the form correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is untested, but I see two things wrong here:

1. You should call `setWebViewClient` with your `WebViewClient` implementation before you call `loadUrl`. However, `loadUrl` is asynchronous, so it probably would not make a difference, but this is worth a try I think.
2. You are not calling `super.onPageFinished(view, url);` in onPageFinshed. You should add this call.

EDIT 2:

I finally took a look at the actual page you are working with. The problem is that the page loads content in a different frame, so you actually have to make the `getElementsByName` call on a different document. The frame in which both of the inputs you want are located has the name `mainFrame` in your page. So, you should write the javascript like this and load that into the `WebView` as you have done above:

```
window.frames["mainFrame"].document.
                 getElementsByName('p_codigo_c')[0].value = "user";
window.frames["mainFrame"].document.
                 getElementsByName('p_clave_c')[0].value = "password";
```

Comment: When I use this: document.getElementsByName('p_codigo_c')[0].value
nothing happend, but when I use: document.getElementsByName('p_codigo_c').value
a new webpage is open with a String I put as value

Comment: @OscarMéndez I took a look at the page. The problem is that you're not  searching within the frame. I have edited my answer. I tested this solution and it works in a desktop web browser. I think it will work in WebView also.

Comment: Thanks for take you the time to check the webpage and help me with this, that works!

Answer (score 5):

this works for me for API version greater than 18

```
 mWebView = findViewById(R.id.web_view);   
        String url = "https://duckduckgo.com";

        mWebView.loadUrl(url);  
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        final String js = "javascript:document.getElementById('search_form_input_homepage').value='android';" +
                "document.getElementById('search_button_homepage').click()";

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19){
                    view.evaluateJavascript(js, new ValueCallback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

here important is view.evaluateJavascript

Comment: Its works for me but I have one question. How to pass static String in value?

Comment: Please look into this sample https://www.codexpedia.com/android/javascript-interface-for-android-and-javascript-communication/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to enable domelements

```
      myview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

and then use getelementby id like

```
     javascript:var x = document.getElementById('myfield').value = 'aaa';
```

and do this in

```
         onPageFinishedLoading(){}
```

got this from the link [Android WebView always returns null for javascript getElementById on loadUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25602117/android-webview-always-returns-null-for-javascript-getelementbyid-on-loadurl/25606090#25606090)

Answer (score 0):

For me, it is required to fill multiple entries in form one by one on callback of 
 each "webView.evaluateJavascript"
Note: API version > 18

See below snippet for reference

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
arr.add("document.getElementsByName(\"tag_name\")[0].value  = \"your_value\";");
.
.
.
call setValue(arr, 0)

private void setValue(final ArrayList<String> arr, final int i) {
        if (i < arr.size()) {
            webView.evaluateJavascript(arr.get(i), new ValueCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
                    int j = i + 1;
                    setValue(arr, j);
                }
            });
        }else{
            webView.evaluateJavascript("document.getElementById(\"your_form_id\").submit();", new ValueCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Submitted: "+value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```