# Android WebView always returns null for javascript getElementById on loadUrl

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

I try to fill out a form inside a webview from the android client app. I know how it should work, but the getElementById always returns null for me. I tried it on different websites.

Here is my example for www.google.com.

```
MyWebView view = new MyWebView(this);
view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
view.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView v, String url) {
        v.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView v, String url) {
        v.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('mib').value = 'aaa';");              
    }
});
setContentView(view);
```

And the MyWebView class (only for information).

```
class MyWebView extends WebView {
    Context context;
    public MyWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // do some multi touch stuff
        return true;
    }
}
```

I always get the error:

```
09-01 04:35:26.453: I/chromium(2962): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null", source: https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl (1)
```

But the element "mib" should be on the site. Using a desktop browser (chrome with mobile simulation) everything is working fine. I have no idea, whats going wrong here.

Thanks for hints!

Edit:
I got some progress. Regarding [this](http://trentmilton.com/android-webview.html) site, I also need setDomStorageEnabled(true).
No I can find the DOM object and set the value, but instead of showing the modified site I get a new blank one with only the value I set. E.g. a white blank site with the text "aaa".

Comment: i think u want to use webview with WebViewClient

Comment: But view is from the type WebView.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Finally I found a solution! And it is a really strange behaviour.

First of all you need to specify setDomStorageEnabled(true) on your webview. Otherwise the DOM doesn't work. I wonder why no tutorial gave a hint about. But ok.

```
myview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

After this I ended up in a white blank page with only the value I set. The strange thing is, that `javascript:document.getElementById('myfield').value = 'aaa';` returns a value. Namely the one I set. So a new blank page was created that only contains the string "aaa".

I solved it by modifying the javascript to throw away the return result:

```
javascript:var x = document.getElementById('myfield').value = 'aaa';
```

And voilá. It is working.

Comment: Actually, Your issue not happened before Android 4.4, 

Since Google already changed to [`new WebView`](http://readwrite.com/2013/11/07/android-kitkat-developers-users) is more better from Android 4.4 version.

Comment: I don't know why, but actually codes need put declare thing as "var x". Now It's work.

Comment: Like a BOSS !! @Catscratch. Like a BOSS !!

Comment: any full example , please .

Comment: @catscratch please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644551/auto-fill-forms-in-webview-by-javascript-android . it needs help.

Answer (score 15):

I also struggled with this issue for quite some time. I had the same issue with the blank page as @Catscratch and nothing worked. Strangely enough, if you wrap the same code in a Javascript function, it all works.

Thus,

```
 webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementById('email_field').value = '" + email + "'; })()");
```

works, while

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('email_field').value = '" + email + "';");
```

does not work.

And all of this **without** needing `setDomStorageEnabled(true)` and without `setWebChromeClient()`

Comment: Can you suggest me where i have to pass main URL or pass main URL and than i loadUrl of javascript

Comment: None of these work. `document.getElementsByTagName('a');` returns undefined inside WebView but works when accessed on desktop

Answer (score 0):

Another work around that seems to work: make sure you javascript "returns" null, ex:

```
loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('myfield').value = 'aaa'; null");
```

Oddly however, if you aren't using `getElementById` then it's OK for loadUrl to return values, the same behavior doesn't occur.  Smells like some kind of bug...it might be [this bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=489241) but possibly not fixed in some versions of android [?]