# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of > null" in Android

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview, android-4.4-kitkat

I try to update information through `java script code in Android side`.

On Android version 4.3, it's work.

But Android version 4.4, it appeared these error, so can not update information.

> [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of
>   null", source:  (1) I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError:
>   Cannot set property 'value' of null", source:  (1) I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'submit' of
>   null", source:  (1)

I know from Android version 4.4, already used new [`Web View`](http://readwrite.com/2013/11/07/android-kitkat-developers-users) to support, but i don't know where is main issue.

People who know how to update information successfully via Java script code even on Android 4.4,

Please tell me,

Thanks you,

p/s : Codes

```
// Load Web View to update new SSID, Security Key, Security Mode
            WebView mWv = new WebView(this);
            // Simplest usage: note that an exception will NOT be thrown
            // if there is an error loading this page (see below).

            mWv.loadUrl("http://" + Constants.IP + "/cgi-bin/input");

            mWv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

            mWv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

            mWv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                public void onPageFinished(WebView mWv, String url) {
                    super.onPageFinished(mWv, url);

                    /**
                     * Pass parametes :
                     * - New SSID
                     * - New Security Key
                     * - Display raw picture
                     */
                    // @"document.getElementsByName('%@')[0].value='%@'"
                    mWv.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('wifi_ssid').value='" +
                                        mEtSSID.getText().toString() + "'");

                    if (mEtSecurityKey.length() == 0
                            | Utils.checkValidatePassword(mEtSecurityKey, 8)) {
                        mWv.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('wifi_key').value='" +
                                            mEtSecurityKey.getText().toString() + "'");

                        if (mCbDisplayRawPicture.isChecked())
                            mWv.loadUrl(
                                    "javascript:document.getElementById('displayraw').value='checked'");
                        else
                            mWv.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('displayraw').value=''");

                        // @"document.forms['sendForm'].submit()"
                        mWv.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('sendForm').submit()");

                        /**
                         * Also get new SSID and new Security Key in Card Setting page
                         */
                        IS_BACK_FROM_CHANGE_SSID_AND_SCCURITY_KEY_TO_CARD_SETTING_PAGE = true;

                        /**
                         * Finish current Change SSID And Security Key after submit success
                         */
                        finish();
                    } else
                        Toast.makeText(SettingAndReviewSettingPage.this,
                                       getString(R.string.toast_your_password_is_case_sensitive),
                                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }

            });
```

**SOLUTION**

I surprised when I find out the solution. I need define the variables for Java script codes. Like following code & it worked.

```
mWv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                public void onPageFinished(WebView mWv, String url) {
                    super.onPageFinished(mWv, url);

                    /**
                     * Pass parametes :
                     * - New SSID
                     * - New Security Key
                     * - Display raw picture
                     */
                    // @"document.getElementsByName('%@')[0].value='%@'"

                    mWv.loadUrl("javascript:var x = document.getElementById('wifi_ssid').value = '" +
                                        mEtSSID.getText().toString() + "';");

                    // need check password is correct or not
                    // - empty or minimum has 8 characters.
                    // - have both character & number in typed password
                    if ((mEtSecurityKey.length() == 0
                            | Utils.checkValidatePassword(mEtSecurityKey, 8)
                            & Utils.checkValidatePassword(mEtSecurityKey.getText().toString()))) {
                        mWv.loadUrl("javascript:var y = document.getElementById('wifi_key').value = '" +
                                            mEtSecurityKey.getText().toString() + "';");

                        if (mCbDisplayRawPicture.isChecked())
                            mWv.loadUrl("javascript:var z = document.getElementById('displayraw').value='checked'");
                        else
                            mWv.loadUrl("javascript:var z = document.getElementById('displayraw').value=''");

                        // @"document.forms['sendForm'].submit()"
                        // mWv.loadUrl("javascript:console.log('sendForm: '+document.getElementById('sendForm').value);");
                        mWv.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('sendForm').submit()");

                        /**
                         * Also get new SSID and new Security Key in Card Setting page
                         */
                        IS_BACK_FROM_CHANGE_SSID_AND_SCCURITY_KEY_TO_CARD_SETTING_PAGE = true;

                        /**
                         * Finish current Change SSID And Security Key after submit success
                         */
                        finish();
                    } else
                        Toast.makeText(
                                ChangeSSIDAndPasswordPage.this,
                                getString(R.string.toast_your_password_is_case_sensitive),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Have a look at the accepted solution here (it worked for me) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25602117/android-webview-always-returns-null-for-javascript-getelementbyid-on-loadurl

Comment: @dgtale Actually your solution not worked for me. Sr. I already find out the solution. Need edit Java script code suitably. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I surprised when I find out the solution. I need define the variables for Java script codes. Like following code `javascript:var x =` & it worked.

```
mWv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                public void onPageFinished(WebView mWv, String url) {
                    super.onPageFinished(mWv, url);

                    /**
                     * Pass parametes :
                     * - New SSID
                     * - New Security Key
                     * - Display raw picture
                     */
                    // @"document.getElementsByName('%@')[0].value='%@'"

                    mWv.loadUrl("javascript:var x = document.getElementById('wifi_ssid').value = '" +
                                        mEtSSID.getText().toString() + "';");

                    // need check password is correct or not
                    // - empty or minimum has 8 characters.
                    // - have both character & number in typed password
                    if ((mEtSecurityKey.length() == 0
                            | Utils.checkValidatePassword(mEtSecurityKey, 8)
                            & Utils.checkValidatePassword(mEtSecurityKey.getText().toString()))) {
                        mWv.loadUrl("javascript:var y = document.getElementById('wifi_key').value = '" +
                                            mEtSecurityKey.getText().toString() + "';");

                        if (mCbDisplayRawPicture.isChecked())
                            mWv.loadUrl("javascript:var z = document.getElementById('displayraw').value='checked'");
                        else
                            mWv.loadUrl("javascript:var z = document.getElementById('displayraw').value=''");

                        // @"document.forms['sendForm'].submit()"
                        // mWv.loadUrl("javascript:console.log('sendForm: '+document.getElementById('sendForm').value);");
                        mWv.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('sendForm').submit()");

                        /**
                         * Also get new SSID and new Security Key in Card Setting page
                         */
                        IS_BACK_FROM_CHANGE_SSID_AND_SCCURITY_KEY_TO_CARD_SETTING_PAGE = true;

                        /**
                         * Finish current Change SSID And Security Key after submit success
                         */
                        finish();
                    } else
                        Toast.makeText(
                                ChangeSSIDAndPasswordPage.this,
                                getString(R.string.toast_your_password_is_case_sensitive),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 7):

The simple solution is to ensure the WebView has the following setting enabled:

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this); // this is the context
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

This allows the browser to store a DOM model of the page elements, so that Javascript can perform operations on it.

Hint: This works only from api 7.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
 wv.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('xx').value='';void(0);");
```

To prevent browser from redirecting to a plain text version of the result of evaluating that JavaScript append the JavaScript string with `void(0);`

Reference: [void](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) operator