# How to make webview remember Usercredentials like username and passwords after logout for auto-fill purpose in android?

Tags: java, android, webview

i have tried to inspect through HTML code from Webview to get the password field and username field ids to execute with javascript.

```
try{
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        htmlcode=document.body().toString();
     }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return "Executed";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

We just need to add `this.webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);` along with `this.webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`.

Now we can delete the cookies codes, and save data.

**Note:** If it doesn't work, try not to delete the cookies code.

Comment: thank you but how to make webview autofill after logout from particular websites ? like other browsers

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977781/fill-form-programmatically-in-android-webview-javascript/24977839#24977839